# Why doesn't the derived constructor get called when instantiating via a metaclass class factory?

Tags: delphi, class, constructor

I'm trying to create what I understand to be a Class Factory in Delphi 2007.  I want to pass a derived class type into a function and have it construct an object of that class type.

I've found some good references, such as [How can I create an Delphi object from a class reference and ensure constructor execution?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/791069/652511), but I still can't get it to work quite right.  In the test below, I can't get it to call the derived constructor, even though the debugger tells me that oClass is TMyDerived.

I think I'm confused about something fundamental here and could use some explanation.  Thanks.

```
program ClassFactoryTest;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
uses
  SysUtils;

//  BASE CLASS
type
  TMyBase = class(TObject)
    bBaseFlag : boolean;
    constructor Create; virtual;
  end;
  TMyBaseClass = class of TMyBase;

constructor TMyBase.Create;
begin
  bBaseFlag := false;
end;

//  DERIVED CLASS
type
  TMyDerived = class(TMyBase)
    bDerivedFlag : boolean;
    constructor Create;
  end;

constructor TMyDerived.Create;
begin
  inherited;
  bDerivedFlag := false;
end;

var
  oClass: TMyBaseClass;
  oBaseInstance, oDerivedInstance: TMyBase;
begin
  oClass := TMyBase;
  oBaseInstance := oClass.Create;

  oClass := TMyDerived;
  oDerivedInstance := oClass.Create;  // <-- Still calling Base Class constructor
end.
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You neglected to specify `override` on the derived class constructor. (I would have expected a warning from the compiler about hiding the base-class method.) Add that, and you should see `TMyDerived.Create` called.

```
TMyDerived = class(TMyBase)
  bDerivedFlag : boolean;
  constructor Create; override;
end;
```

An alternative, since your constructors take no parameters, is to forgo virtual constructors and just override `AfterConstruction`.

Comment: +1, but... `is to forgo virtual constructors and just override AfterConstruction.` Urgh how very confusingly non-standard. Please stick with constructors

Comment: The only problem with using `AfterConstruction` for this is that it doesn't make the intent clear. It would be easy to subclass and add a non overridden constructor. A virtual constructor makes this clear. That said, if you made this mistake, your code would not work which I always find to be an excellent safety net!