# Polymorphism and inheritance using class reference (part 2)?

Tags: class, delphi, inheritance, reference, polymorphism

The console application below gives "Runtime error"...

Why would this happen ? Many thanks !

PS: [Related SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23627783)

```
program Project2;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

type
  TParent = class;
  TParentClass = class of TParent;

  TParent = class
  public
    procedure Work; virtual; abstract;
  end;

  TChild1 = class(TParent)
  public
    procedure Work; override;
  end;

  TChild2 = class(TParent)
  public
    procedure Work; override;
  end;

procedure TChild1.Work;
begin
  WriteLn('Child1 Work');
end;

procedure TChild2.Work;
begin
  WriteLn('Child2 Work');
end;

procedure Test(ImplClass: TParentClass);
var
  ImplInstance: TParent;
begin
  ImplInstance := ImplClass.Create;
  ImplInstance.Work;
  ImplInstance.Free;
end;

begin
  Test(TParent);
  Test(TChild1);
  Test(TChild2);
  Readln;
end.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `TParent.Work` method is declared as `abstract`. The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Methods#Abstract_Methods) says:

> You can call an abstract method only in a class or instance of a class in which the method has been overridden.

When you call `TParent.Work` you break that rule and so encounter a runtime error.

Comment: But TChild1 has overriden the Work in TParent ?

Comment: You call `Test(TParent)` and so create an instance of `TParent`. Thus when you call `Work` on that instance, you bind to `TParent.Work`.

Comment: That is why it would have been nice if `class abstract` actually worked.

Comment: @StefanGlienke `class abstract` is a hangover from the .net compiler right? If I recall correctly, C# abstract classes cannot be instantiated. But that can be enforced at compile time because C# does not have meta classes.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Exactly, you can write it but it does nothing (i.e. it does not prevent you from instantiating said class).