# Does the construction of an object through a class variable always need the parent class to have a constructor?

Tags: class, delphi, constructor, delphi-xe2

A bit of a convoluted question, I know, and I'm sure someone is at hand to simplify it to its basics.

Consider the following code:

```
TTestClass = class
public
end;

TTestClassDescendant = class(TTestClass)
public
  constructor Create;
end;


implementation

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var tc: TTestClass;
begin
  tc := TTestClassDescendant.Create;
  tc.Free;
end;

{ TTestClassDescendant }

constructor TTestClassDescendant.Create;
begin
  ShowMessage('Create executed')  // this gets executed
end;
```

The Create procedure gets executed properly.

Now consider following code:

```
TTestClass = class
public
end;

TTestClassDescendant = class(TTestClass)
public
  constructor Create;
end;

TTestClassClass = class of TTestClass;

implementation

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var tc: TTestClass;
    tcc: TTestClassClass;
begin
  tcc := TTestClassDescendant;
  tc := tcc.Create;
  tc.Free
end;

{ TTestClassDescendant }

constructor TTestClassDescendant.Create;
begin
  ShowMessage('Create executed')  // this does NOT get executed
end;
```

The Create procedure of the descendant class does not get executed anymore.

However, if I introduce a constructor in the parent class and override it in the descendant class, it does get executed:

```
TTestClass = class
public
  constructor Create; virtual;
end;

TTestClassDescendant = class(TTestClass)
public
  constructor Create; override;
end;
```

Pardon me if I'm overlooking the obvious, but shouldn't the constructor code in that second block of code be executed when the construction occurs through a class variable, just as it is when it is called through the class identifier itself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Pardon me if I'm overlooking the obvious, but shouldn't the
>   constructor code in that second block of code be executed when the
>   construction occurs through a class variable, just as it is when it is
>   called through the class identifier itself?

No, it shouldn't.

The declaration is

```
TTestClassClass = class of TTestClass; // note: of TTestClass!
```

and that is why the (empty) constructor of the base `TTestClass` (which it inherited from `TObject`) gets called, because that is the ***declared*** class a `TTestClassClass` refers to.

If you want the ***actual*** constructor to be called, then you should make the constructor **virtual** in the base class and **override** in the descendant, as you did in the last part of your question.

---

FWIW, if you declare a

```
TTestClassDescendantClass = class of TTestClassDescendant;
```

and then use that to instantiate a descendant class, then you should indeed get a `TTestClassDescendant` and the constructor should display what you expected.

### Analogy

But this behaviour of the constructor is just like for other non-virtual and virtual methods:

```
type
  TBase = class
    procedure DoSomething; // outputs: "TBase: Doing something"
  end;

  TDesc = class(TBase)
    procedure DoSomething; // outputs: "Descendant does it now"
  end;

var
  D: TBase;
begin
  D := TDesc.Create;
  D.DoSomething;
```

Since `D` is declared as `TBase`, the call to `D.DoSomething` will call `TBase.DoSomething`, not `TDesc.DoSomething`.

But if `DoSomething` is **virtual** and **overridden** in `TDesc`, then the **actual** class in `D` will be used. The example you gave works the same, except that you are using metaclasses there.

Comment: I was expecting it to behave in exactly the same way as tc := TTestClassDescendant.Create because all I did was replace TTestClassDescendant by tcc, which is a variable containing TTestClassDescendant. It's pretty counterintuitive that it doesn't behave in the same way.

Comment: Not really counterintuitive. The method resolution happens at compile time unless the method is virtual or dynamic.

Comment: If I have
tc := TTestClassDescendant.Create calling the proper procedure and
tcc := TTestClassDescendant;
tc := tcc.Create not calling it, it's pretty counterintuitive, no? tcc is nothing more than TTestClassDescendant. They ought to be identical.

Comment: Nope. tcc is a class reference. Compiler wires up the method call at compile time. It doesn't know what will be in the reference at runtime.

Comment: Okidoki. I think this might be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/791069/how-can-i-create-an-delphi-object-from-a-class-reference-and-ensure-constructor

Comment: I would like to add, if for any reason declaring virtual constructor(s) is not an option, there's always a virtual `AfterConstruction` method defined in `TObject` ready for you to override, just for this case where you would like to have decendant classes do something upon construction.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Stijn.

Comment: (haha, looks like I did back in [2009 as well](https://stackoverflow.com/a/792434/87971))

Comment: No, it is not counterintuitive. It is just as with non-constructor methods. The *declared* class defines which method is called, if the method is not virtual. The *actual* class defines it when the method is virtual.

Comment: FWIW, @Domus? Do I know you?

Comment: After sixty years of Delphi use, this is the first time this bit me. After a long walk and short contemplation, it all makes perfect sense, though. It is indeed 100% in line with the Delphi VMT paradigm. It's good to sometimes descend the abstraction ladder into the basement and refresh one's mind. Yes, you do know me. You once pulled all my teeth in order to buy a fancy car!

Comment: @Domus: "sixty years of Delphi use". Yes, I know you. But for my fancy car, I had to pull a few more teeth. <g>